# I can't delete my image when it is liked because of the foreign key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

There is the schema of my db :

[image]

And I've got this error message when I try to delete a picture :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`scores`, CONSTRAINT `scores_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`picture_id`) REFERENCES `pictures` (`id`)) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/legogram/app/model/model.php:173
```

When my image is not liked, I can delete it but when it is liked, I can not

Here is the function to list my images :

```
    public function listPictures_session()
{
    $this->open();
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT pictures.id, pictures.owner_id, pictures.title, pictures.description, pictures.path,
    SUM(scores.score)/COUNT(scores.id) AS 'score'
    FROM pictures LEFT OUTER JOIN scores ON pictures.id=scores.picture_id 
    GROUP BY pictures.id
    ORDER BY pictures.id DESC LIMIT 100");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

And how I call it in my view :

```
    $pictures = $this->model->listPictures_session(); 
foreach ($pictures as $picture) { 
if ($picture["owner_id"] == $_SESSION["id"]) { 
echo picture["id"] }"
```

But I do not select scores.id in the select of my listPictures_session function. So I tried to add a `SELECT scores.id`, So I can delete it in first place. But when I try to add `scores.id` to the `SELECT` I have a `GROUP BY` error.

I was adding the `scores.id` this way but it was not working :

```
    SELECT pictures.id, pictures.owner_id, pictures.title, pictures.description, pictures.path,
    SUM(scores.score)/COUNT(scores.id) AS 'score', scores.id
```

And the function to delete it :

```
    public function deletepicture($user)
{
    $this->open();
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id=:id");
    return $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $user["id"]));
}
```

How can I fix this problem so I can delete my image? Thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: `I still get a mysql error because of the GROUP BY`...what do you mean? You can't group in a DELETE. You need to delete actual rows, not aggregated calculations. Show us specifically what DELETE query you tried to execute in order to remove the likes.

Comment: Also bear in mind we cannot actually see anything about your schema and you also provided no sample data, so we are working blind. Consider editing your question. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: Your `scores` table seem to have a foreign key constrain to the `pictures` table. If you want to delete an pictures, you first need to delete all references to that pictures in the other tables.

Comment: I mean the "listpictures_session" function's GROUP BY. I tried to add "scores.id" to the select but when I do that, I have an error related to the GROUP BY

Comment: Ok. But from your post it seems we're talking about deleting, not selecting? You'll need to [edit] the question to clarify properly what you are trying to do with this select, and how it relates to your question about deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, what you actually want to do is delete a row from the `pictures` table. You have a foreign key constraint in `scores` on `scores.picture_id` that references `pictures.id`. These are good things.

Your error message is as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`scores`, CONSTRAINT `scores_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`picture_id`) REFERENCES `pictures` (`id`)) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/legogram/app/model/model.php:173
```

which means that this foreign key constraint is being violated when trying to delete the row in the `pictures` table. This is caused by one or more rows in the `scores` table with a `picture_id` that reference `pictures.id`. You cannot delete the row in `pictures` without eliminating all the references to it. You can either set the reference to `null` if the referencing column allows `null`, or you could delete the row altogether. From what I can tell, this table is used to store users' ratings of other users' pictures, and rows in this table don't make sense without the picture ID it references, so your best approach here is probably to delete the offending rows altogether. You can do this as a part of the delete process:

```
public function deletepicture($user) {
    $this->open();
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
            <<<SQL
            DELETE FROM
                scores
            WHERE
                picture_id = :pictureId
            SQL
        );
    $stmt->execute([
            ":pictureId" => $user["id"]
        ]);
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
            <<<SQL
            DELETE FROM
                pictures
            WHERE
                id = :id
            SQL
        );
    return $stmt->execute([
            ":id" => $user["id"]
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

foreign key of table `` (`test`.`scores`) `` reference to table `pictures`

you must delete records of `` (`test`.`scores`) `` reference to `pictures` before delete record of `pictures`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your GROUP BY error is relevant to your actual issue.

Basically if you have rows in `scores` which refer to a specific picture ID, then you must delete all rows from `scores` which contain that picture ID before you can delete the related row in `pictures`.

e.g.

```
DELETE FROM scores WHERE picture_id = :id

DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id = :id
```

Comment: Ok I understand, so I do a first function to delete the scores and a second one to delete the picture ? In my view I was doing this loop : 

"$pictures = $this->model->listPictures_session();

foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
                    if ($picture["owner_id"] == $_SESSION["id"]) { echo picture["id"] }"

But when I tried to add "scores.id" to the listPictures_session() function I had a GROUP BY error

Comment: Yeah I don't really see why you'd need to do anything in your loop to get the score ID. You don't need to know any specific score ID - you can just delete all scores which have the relevant picture ID, as I've shown.